# Question about bitwise And and Shift operations

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How exactly do the following lines work if `pData = "abc"`?

```
pDes[1] = ( pData[0] & 0x1c ) >> 2;
pDes[0] = ( pData[0] << 6 ) | ( pData[1] & 0x3f );
```

Comment: Why don't you run them and see?

Comment: You are using the `'a'` twice and the `'c'` not at all. Are you sure this code is as intended?

Comment: To the closers: How exactly is this not a programming-related question? That sure looks like C++ code to me and SO is meant to be for _all_ skill levels, including those that don't know diddly about bitwise operators.

Comment: It looks like maybe you're trying to implement part of some sort of base64 encoder.  If that's what you want, why don't you ask that question instead?  Basically, what's the larger context of your question so you can get a better and more complete answer.  :-)

Comment: _Could_ be base64, but I'd expect the decode (3 bytes to 2) would use 0xfc rather than 0x1c (0x1c is only three bits, not six) and pDes[1] would need to be built from pData[0] _and_ [1]. So I'm not so sure. Excellent catch though, if you're right @Omni.

Comment: yeah yeah..thats good catch ..m doing the same.. but u know i really want to know the logic behind ..basically i want to do character conversions ... like from UTF8toJIS format if anybody can tell me logic ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, assuming ASCII which is by no means guaranteed, `pData[0]` is `'a'` (`0x61`) and `pData[1]` is `'b'` (`0x62`):

```
pDes[1]:
    pData[0]               0110 0001
    &0x1c                  0001 1100
                           ---- ----
                           0000 0000
    >>2                    0000 0000  0x00

pDes[0]:
    pData[0]               0110 0001

    << 6           01 1000 0100 0000 (interim value *a)

    pData[1]               0110 0010
    &0x3f                  0011 1111
                   -- ---- ---- ----
                           0010 0010
    |(*a)          01 1000 0100 0000
                   -- ---- ---- ----
                   01 1000 0110 0010  0x1862
```

How it works:

`<< N` simply means shift the bits `N` spaces to the left, `>> N` is the same but shifting to the right.

The `&` (`and`) operation will set each bit of the result to 1 if and only if the corresponding bit in both inputs is 1.

The `|` (`or`) operations sets each bit of the result to 1 if one or more of the corresponding bit in both inputs is 1.

Note that the 0x1862 will be truncated to fit into `pDes[0]` if it's type is not wide enough.

The folowing C program shows this in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *pData = "abc";
    int pDes[2];
    pDes[1] = ( pData[0] & 0x1c ) >> 2;
    pDes[0] = ( pData[0] << 6 ) | ( pData[1] & 0x3f );
    printf ("%08x %08x\n", pDes[0], pDes[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
00001862 00000000
```

and, when you change `pDes` to a char array, you get:

```
00000062 00000000
```

Comment: If `pDes` is an int array upper bits of `'a' << 6` does matter - it is not ANDed with `0x3f` - it is ORed with `'b' & 0x3f`

Comment: I found this answer easier to follow than the other one that's a decent answer.

Comment: @Amargosh, yes, I had a rethink about that and you're dead right, the interim is treated as a larger type. Edited to fix.

Comment: Thanks you guies...i really need this :)

Answer (score 2):

`&` is not logical AND - it is bit-wise AND.

`a` is 0x61, thus `pData[0] & 0x1c` gives

```
0x61 0110 0001  
0x1c 0001 1100
--------------
     0000 0000
```

`>> 2` shifts this to right by two positions - value doesn't change as all bits are zero.

`pData[0] << 6` left shifts `0x61` by 6 bits to give `01000000` or `0x40`

```
pData[1] & 0x3f

0x62 0110 0010
0x3f 0011 1111
--------------
0x22 0010 0010
```

Thus it comes down to `0x40 | 0x22` - again `|` is not logical OR, it is bit-wise.

```
0x40 0100 0000
0x22 0010 0010
--------------
0x62 0110 0010
```

The results will be different if `pDes` is not a char array. Left shifting `0x61` would give you `0001 1000 0100 0000` or `0x1840` - (in case `pDes` is a char array, the left parts are not in the picture).

```
0x1840 0001 1000 0100 0000
0x0022 0000 0000 0010 0010
--------------------------
0x1862 0001 1000 0110 0010
```

`pDes[0]` would end up as `0x1862` or decimal `6242`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ will treat a character as a number according to it's encoding.  So, assuming ASCII, 'a' is 97 (which has a bit pattern of 0110_0001) and 'b' is 98 (bit pattern 0110_0010).

Once you think of them as numbers, bit operations on characters should be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In C, all characters are also integers. That means `"abc"` is equivalent to `(char[]){0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0}`.

The `&` is *not* the logical AND operator (`&&`). It is the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_AND#AND), which computes the AND at bit-level, e.g.

```
      'k' = 0x6b ->    0 1 1 0  1 0 1 1
            0x1c ->    0 0 0 1  1 1 0 0   (&
                    ———————————————————
               8 <-    0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0
```

The main purpose of `& 0x1c` here is to extract bits #2 ~ #4 from `pData[0]`. The `>> 2` afterwards remove the extra zeros at the end.

Similarly, the `& 0x3f` is to extract bits #0 ~ #5 from `pData[1]`.

The `<< 6` pushes 6 zeros at the least significant end of the bits. Assuming `pDes[0]` is also a `char`, the most significant 6 bits will be discarded:

```
     'k' = 0x6b ->                      0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
                    << 6 = 0 1 1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
                           xxxxxxxxxxx—————————————————
           0xc0 <-                      1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

In terms of bits, if

```
                 pData[1]                    pData[0]

pData -> b7 b6 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1 b0     a7 a6 a5 a4 a3 a2 a1 a0
```

then

```
pDes  ->  0  0  0  0  0 a4 a3 a2     a1 a0 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1 b0     

                 pDes[1]                     pDes[0]
```

This looks like an operation to pack three values into a 6-5-5 bit structure.